# Low Side Bus One Shot

Tags: differential, bus

I'm  confused on what exactly a one shot is and how to identify it on prints. For this example I know there is supposed to be a one shot on the low side of a 69 kV / 12 kV bus, but I'm not sure how exactly it's typically depicted on prints.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add some context what sort of design this is for, and include any picture of the _prints_.

Comment: Low side bus one shot was my nickname in college